Tikz figure arrowstyle for Schematic energy band representation of a semiconductor
I'm trying to replicate the arrow style from one TikZ figure in another. Specifically, I want to change the arrows in the first image to match those in the second image.
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Drawing the valence band
    \fill[cyan!90] (-2,0) rectangle (2,0.5);
    \draw[thick] (-2,0) -- (2,0) node[midway, below, yshift=-2mm] {Valence band};
    
    % Drawing the conduction band
    \draw[thick] (-2,2) -- (2,2) node[midway, above, yshift=2mm] {Conduction band};

    % Drawing the energy gap label
    \draw[thick, <->] (2.2,0.1) -- (2.2,1.9) node[midway, right] {$E_g \sim 1 \text{ eV}$};
    
    % Drawing electrons in the conduction band
    \filldraw[black] (-1.5,2) circle (2pt);
    \filldraw[black] (-0.5,2) circle (2pt);
    \filldraw[black] (0.5,2) circle (2pt);
    \filldraw[black] (1.5,2) circle (2pt);
    
    % Drawing holes in the valence band
    \filldraw[white, thick] (-1.5,0.25) circle (2pt);
    \draw[thick] (-1.5,0.25) circle (2pt);
    
    \filldraw[white, thick] (-0.5,0.25) circle (2pt);
    \draw[thick] (-0.5,0.25) circle (2pt);
    
    \filldraw[white, thick] (0.5,0.25) circle (2pt);
    \draw[thick] (0.5,0.25) circle (2pt);
    
    \filldraw[white, thick] (1.5,0.25) circle (2pt);
    \draw[thick] (1.5,0.25) circle (2pt);
   
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Schematic energy band representation of a semiconductor}
\end{figure}

I want to modify only the arrows in the energy gap label so that they look like the arrows in the second image (which has arrows with a smaller head and a more compact design). How can I achieve this in TikZ? Any specific styling tips or adjustments to the arrow geometry would be greatly appreciated.



Welcome. // I‘m irritated, as we saw the same diagram before (which still is physically incorrect). // Just draw two lines, which have the arrow tip only on one side … // BTW try copy and compile your code snippet … and then add the missing lines, please.

Changing \begin{tikzpicture} to \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex] should already do. But as in the other comments already suggested, please make your code snippet a compilable minimal working example.

I'm sorry if I sounded annoying but as a non-expert Latex user which is trying to learn I just asked for help.  If there is any way to create a better version of this tikzpicture, please enlight me.
